# can't change backgrund border of qtextedit in Pyqt5, any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I could not change the background shape of the text. Is it possible or should i try another way to get it solved. Thanks. This what i have so far. I tried to add broder-radius to html in qtextedit but whenever i tried QtCreator did not accept what i have done and reset the code to the current html i shared now.

```
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
font.setPointSize(8)
font.setStrikeOut(False)
self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(143,188,143))
self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
self.ui.textEdit.append("Here is the background i want to change. Iwant it to be round instead of a corner.")
self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(self.ui.textEdit_2.LineWrapMode(3))        
self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(40)
self.ui.textEdit.setWordWrapMode(1)
self.ui.textEdit.append("")
self.ui.textEdit.setFont(font)



self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Mit der Nutzung Des Chatbots stimmen Sie der Nutzung unserer AGB zu.</p></body></html>"))
```

**Here is the whole Code which i tried to run. It is not showing the plain text for any reason and gives me folliwing fault:**

```
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
    

    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import sys, random
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
    from untitled3.mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
    import json
    import requests

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):              
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            #self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
            self.willkommen()
        

    def willkommen(self, parent = None):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(self.ui.textEdit.LineWrapMode(3))        
        self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(40)
        self.ui.textEdit.setWordWrapMode(1)
        self.ui.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.ui.textEdit.setPlainText("Willkommen. Ich bin Evossistant und beantworte Ihre Fragen.\
Bitte lesen Sie die AGB, bevor Sie den Chatbot nutzen.")
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.nutzereingabe)
        self.ui.textEdit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        self.ui.textEdit.paintEvent = self.paintEvent(None)
        

    def paintEvent(self, event):        
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.ui.textEdit.viewport())    
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143, 50))
        pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143, 50))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        doc = self.ui.textEdit.document()
        margin = doc.documentMargin()
        rightAlignmentStart = self.ui.textEdit.size().width()
        natruralTextWidth = 0
        unitedBlockRect = QtCore.QRectF()
        for b in range(doc.blockCount()):
            block = doc.findBlockByNumber(b)
            blockRect = doc.documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
            layout = block.layout()           
            lineRect = QtCore.QRectF()
            for k in range(layout.lineCount()):
                line = layout.lineAt(k)
                linerect = line.rect()
                naturalTextWidth = max(line.naturalTextWidth(), natruralTextWidth)
                #if self.ui.textEdit.alignment() == QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:         
                rightAlignmentStart = min(rightAlignmentStart, self.ui.textEdit.size().width() - naturalTextWidth - margin) 
                lineRect = lineRect.united(linerect)
            unitedBlockRect = blockRect.united(lineRect)    
        unitedBlockRect.setX(rightAlignmentStart - 20)       
        #I think it is better you keep a extra width.
        unitedBlockRect.setWidth(unitedBlockRect.width() )
        painter.drawRoundedRect(unitedBlockRect, 10, 10)        
        #return QtWidgets.QTextEdit.paintEvent(self, event)

    
    def nutzereingabe(self):
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
        #self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(176, 224, 230))
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.ui.textEdit.append(text)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
        Dict_to_send = {"sender": "user_name", "message": text}
        print(Dict_to_send)
        self.request(Dict_to_send)

    
    def request(self,Dict_to_send):
    
        Url = "http://127.0.0.1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
        r = requests.post(Url, json = Dict_to_send)
        print(r.text)
        b = r.text       
        if "text" in b:
            a = (b.strip('"]}').split(":")[2])
            message = a.replace('"', "")
            self.botausgabe(message)
        else:
            message = "keine Antwort"
            self.botausgabe(message)

    def botausgabe(self, message):       
        #self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(143,188,143))
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.ui.textEdit.append(message)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
       
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:/Users/Polat/Desktop/ChatGUI/untitled3\mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(500, 600)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Desktop/ChatbotProgrammierung/evocenta.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(255.0)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 200));\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabWidget {    \n"
"    \n"
"    border:None;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabWidget::pane {  \n"
"border: 0;    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {    \n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 100), stop:0.88 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.92 rgba(75, 111, 180, 150), stop:0.96 rgba(148, 27, 128, 150), stop:1 rgba(231, 170, 0, 150));\n"
"\n"
"    Border:none;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;}\n"
"QLineEdit{\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;}")
        MainWindow.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setDockOptions(QtWidgets.QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks|QtWidgets.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.widget.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.frame)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab{    \n"
"background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    border-top-left-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-top-right-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;\n"
"    min-width: 14ex;\n"
"    padding: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {\n"
"    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                stop: 0 #fafafa, stop: 0.4 #f4f4f4,\n"
"                                stop: 0.5 #e7e7e7, stop: 1.0 #fafafa);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tab.setStyleSheet("QWidget{    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50);\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame_chat1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_chat1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_chat1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_chat1.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_chat1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame_chat1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_chat1.setObjectName("frame_chat1")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_chat1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_chat1)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(105, 210, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setMarkdown("")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_chat1)
        self.frame_chat2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        self.frame_chat2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.frame_chat2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.frame_chat2.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.frame_chat2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_chat2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_chat2.setObjectName("frame_chat2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_chat2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_chat2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_chat2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 30))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(115, 174, 76, 100);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_chat2)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tab_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget{    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50);\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.frame_agb = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_agb.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_agb.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_agb.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_agb.setObjectName("frame_agb")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_agb)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_agb)
        self.textEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(105, 210, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.textEdit_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.frame_agb)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Evosisstant - Your Digital Guide"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<h1 style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:xx-large; font-weight:600;\"><br /></h1></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Schreiben Sie hier..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Senden"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Chat"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Mit der Nutzung Des Chatbots stimmen Sie der Nutzung unserer AGB zu.</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Nutzungsbedingungen"))[![enter image description here][1]][1]![enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: and could you share your code?

Comment: if anythin g is missing i try to share ASAP

Comment: Can you please try to explain yourself better? It's not clear what you mean by the "background border" in the title, as in the body of the question you also refer to "background shape of the text" and I really don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I made a dark green background behind my setted text. I want to change the shape of it from rectangular to rounded. So that the background shape has rounded borders or is cicular. i am sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is the backgroundcolor  adopted to your text all around and is it absolutely same color?

Comment: @KadirPlt just to be sure, is what you want to achieve similar to this mock-up? https://i.stack.imgur.com/etHnf.png If not, can you provide a graphical representation of what you want to get?

Comment: Thanks for your responds. Haru, i did not get what you mean. The color of the text ist setted by: self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(143,188,143)). This color is behind every character which is typed in.

Comment: Hello Musicamante. I added a screenshot of whatsapp. As you see behind the written text is a specific background color and shape. So it is possible to differentiate between sender and receiver. In my code i could add a color but was not able to specialize the shape.

Comment: Oh, according to your uploading image, did you want to draw roundedRect  it contained  all area of `QTextBlock` like bubble style? To say, the blank is also contained by the rect? I have been thinking I must delete the unnecessary text space...

Comment: @KadirPlt I ask you to be more precise and clear in your questions, as your request is still somehow confused. You want a "balloon" around group of text, or, paragraph? That *can* be done, but considering the example you're giving, I would certainly **not** use a QTextEdit, since what you're going to do requires much more control than what a QTextEdit could give.

Answer (score 2):

Update2

Sorry, I mistook... you have given me the complete code , I've never been aware of it.In this case , even if I use installEventFilter, the contents of paint is overdrawn by your setStyleSheet settings , and so on.

So I have discovered I can make a subclass of QTextEdit, I did it.
Please try my code again.

[image]

---

Okay, I saw your update, I think you don't understand the system of `eventFilter` enough.Event streams from parent to child.(in this case, easily to say , (QObject)→QApplication→QMainWindow→QTextEdit)

Normally, event is overridden in the subclass of the class directly.

Because you want to draw the viewport of `QTextEdit`, you must override the `paintEvent` in the subclass of `QTextEdit`.But in this case, you made GUI by Qt-Designer.
You cannot write the code for overriding `paintEvent` in `QTextEdit`.

The major way is to get the same effect for overriding paintEvent, for this, you can install eventFilter.At the time of `QMainWindow`, you can change the stream of event.Here, now, I changed the stream only in the case of `self.ui.textEdit` by
`If obj is self.ui.textEdit` flag.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import json
import requests




#we can override if this setting is !
class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEdit, self).__init__(parent)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())    
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143, 255))
        pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143, 255))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        doc = self.document()
        margin = doc.documentMargin()
        rightAlignmentStart = self.size().width()
        natruralTextWidth = 0
        unitedBlockRect = QtCore.QRectF()
        for b in range(doc.blockCount()):
            block = doc.findBlockByNumber(b)
            blockRect = doc.documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
            layout = block.layout()           
            lineRect = QtCore.QRectF()
            for k in range(layout.lineCount()):
                line = layout.lineAt(k)
                linerect = line.rect()
                naturalTextWidth = max(line.naturalTextWidth(), natruralTextWidth)
                #if self.ui.textEdit.alignment() == QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:         
                rightAlignmentStart = min(rightAlignmentStart, self.size().width() - naturalTextWidth - margin) 
                lineRect = lineRect.united(linerect)
            unitedBlockRect = blockRect.united(lineRect)    
        unitedBlockRect.setX(rightAlignmentStart - 20)       
        #I think it is better you keep a extra width.
        unitedBlockRect.setWidth(unitedBlockRect.width() )
        painter.drawRoundedRect(unitedBlockRect, 10, 10)    
        return QtWidgets.QTextEdit.paintEvent(self, event)
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(500, 600)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../Desktop/ChatbotProgrammierung/evocenta.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(255.0)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 200));\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabWidget {    \n"
"    \n"
"    border:None;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabWidget::pane {  \n"
"border: 0;    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QWidget {    \n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 100), stop:0.88 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255), stop:0.92 rgba(75, 111, 180, 150), stop:0.96 rgba(148, 27, 128, 150), stop:1 rgba(231, 170, 0, 150));\n"
"\n"
"    Border:none;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;}\n"
"QLineEdit{\n"
"Border-radius: 10px;}")
        MainWindow.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setDockOptions(QtWidgets.QMainWindow.AllowTabbedDocks|QtWidgets.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.widget.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.frame)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab{    \n"
"background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    border-top-left-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-top-right-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;\n"
"    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;\n"
"    min-width: 14ex;\n"
"    padding: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {\n"
"    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                stop: 0 #fafafa, stop: 0.4 #f4f4f4,\n"
"                                stop: 0.5 #e7e7e7, stop: 1.0 #fafafa);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tab.setStyleSheet("QWidget{    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50);\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame_chat1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_chat1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_chat1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_chat1.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_chat1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.frame_chat1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_chat1.setObjectName("frame_chat1")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_chat1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.textEdit = TextEdit(self.frame_chat1)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(105, 210, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setMarkdown("")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_chat1)
        self.frame_chat2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        self.frame_chat2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.frame_chat2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.frame_chat2.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.frame_chat2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_chat2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_chat2.setObjectName("frame_chat2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_chat2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_chat2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_chat2)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 30))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(115, 174, 76, 100);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_chat2)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.tab_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget{    \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 50);\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.frame_agb = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_agb.setStyleSheet("QFrame{    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(115, 174, 76, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));\n"
"    Border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_agb.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_agb.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_agb.setObjectName("frame_agb")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_agb)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_agb)
        self.textEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);\n"
"    border-color: rgb(105, 210, 255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}")
        self.textEdit_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.frame_agb)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Evosisstant - Your Digital Guide"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<h1 style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:xx-large; font-weight:600;\"><br /></h1></body></html>"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Schreiben Sie hier..."))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Senden"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Chat"))
        self.textEdit_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Mit der Nutzung Des Chatbots stimmen Sie der Nutzung unserer AGB zu.</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Nutzungsbedingungen"))
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):              
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        #self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.willkommen()
        

    def willkommen(self, parent = None):
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(self.ui.textEdit.LineWrapMode(3))        
        self.ui.textEdit.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(40)
        self.ui.textEdit.setWordWrapMode(1)
        self.ui.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.ui.textEdit.setPlainText("Willkommen. Ich bin Evossistant und beantworte Ihre Fragen.\
    Bitte lesen Sie die AGB, bevor Sie den Chatbot nutzen.")
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.ui.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.ui.pushButton.click)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.nutzereingabe)
        self.ui.textEdit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    
        
 
    
    def nutzereingabe(self):
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
        #self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(176, 224, 230))
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.ui.textEdit.append(text)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")
        Dict_to_send = {"sender": "user_name", "message": text}
        print(Dict_to_send)
        self.request(Dict_to_send)
    
    
    def request(self,Dict_to_send):
    
        Url = "http://127.0.0.1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
        r = requests.post(Url, json = Dict_to_send)
        print(r.text)
        b = r.text       
        if "text" in b:
            a = (b.strip('"]}').split(":")[2])
            message = a.replace('"', "")
            self.botausgabe(message)
        else:
            message = "keine Antwort"
            self.botausgabe(message)
    
    def botausgabe(self, message):       
        #self.ui.textEdit.setTextBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(143,188,143))
        self.ui.textEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.ui.textEdit.append(message)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is None else QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Update:
If you want to wrap all texts with the bubble style, please replace the previous code to this.

---

```
#it may be necessary to call repaint() at an appropriate time.
def paintEvent(self, event):        
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())    
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
        pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        doc = self.document()
        margin = doc.documentMargin()
        rightAlignmentStart = self.size().width()
        natruralTextWidth = 0
        unitedBlockRect = QtCore.QRectF()
        for b in range(doc.blockCount()):
            block = doc.findBlockByNumber(b)
            blockRect = doc.documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
            layout = block.layout()           
            lineRect = QtCore.QRectF()
            for k in range(layout.lineCount()):
                line = layout.lineAt(k)
                linerect = line.rect()
                naturalTextWidth = max(line.naturalTextWidth(), natruralTextWidth)
                if self.alignment() == QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:         
                    rightAlignmentStart = min(rightAlignmentStart, self.size().width() - naturalTextWidth - margin) 
                lineRect = lineRect.united(linerect)
            unitedBlockRect = blockRect.united(lineRect)    
        unitedBlockRect.setX(rightAlignmentStart - 20)       
        #I think it is better you keep a extra width.
        unitedBlockRect.setWidth(unitedBlockRect.width() )
        painter.drawRoundedRect(unitedBlockRect, 10, 10)        
        return QtWidgets.QTextEdit.paintEvent(self, event)
```

---

for ui

to change self. →　obj. or self.ui.textEdit

---

**OLD**

please try this code.

you managed to draw rounded rect background.

But the range I can control now is as follows:

1. the backgroundcolor is adopted to texts all around.
2. the color is the same.

If you change something, you must probably think about coding every time.

pls dock the code to yours.

**Note:**

`line.rect()` returns a relative rect of `QTextLine`. The topLeft is (0, 0).
If we use this rect as it is, we cannot draw appropriate rect from the 2nd block.
So I also got `blockBoundingRect` and translated lineRect.This rect contains documentMargin.

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jan  2 12:26:06 2021

@author: Haru
"""
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
class MyEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        #You don't use setBackgroundColor()
        self.setLineWrapMode(self.LineWrapMode(3))        
        self.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(40)
        self.setWordWrapMode(1)
        self.append("")
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setPlainText( "Here is the background i want to change. Iwant it to be round instead of a corner.")
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):        
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
        pen.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        doc = self.document()
        margin = doc.documentMargin()
        for b in range(doc.blockCount()):
            block = doc.findBlockByNumber(b)
            blockRect = doc.documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
            layout = block.layout()           
            for k in range(layout.lineCount()):
                line = layout.lineAt(k)
                lineRect = line.rect()
                lineRect.setWidth(line.naturalTextWidth())
                lineRect.translate(blockRect.x(), blockRect.y())
                if self.alignment() == QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:                    
                    lineRect.setX(self.size().width() - line.naturalTextWidth() - margin)
                    lineRect.setWidth(line.naturalTextWidth())
                painter.drawRoundedRect(lineRect, 2, 2)  
        return QtWidgets.QTextEdit.paintEvent(self, event)
```

Result of my code (in my environment)

[image: backgroundroundedcolortext]

Because you made your widget by Qt-designer, you may not be able to dock my code as it is.
Here is the code. please rewrite the necessary part. **ThisClassName**, and so on.

```
self.ui.textEdit.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Paint:
        if obj is self.ui.textEdit:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(obj.viewport())
            pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
            pen.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(143, 188, 143))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
            doc = obj.document()
            margin = doc.documentMargin()
            for b in range(doc.blockCount()):
                block = doc.findBlockByNumber(b)
                blockRect = doc.documentLayout().blockBoundingRect(block)
                layout = block.layout()           
                for k in range(layout.lineCount()):
                    line = layout.lineAt(k)
                    lineRect = line.rect()
                    lineRect.setWidth(line.naturalTextWidth())
                    lineRect.translate(blockRect.x(), blockRect.y())
                    if self.alignment() == QtCore.Qt.AlignRight:                    
                        lineRect.setX(obj.size().width() - line.naturalTextWidth() - margin)
                        lineRect.setWidth(line.naturalTextWidth())
                    painter.drawRoundedRect(lineRect, 2, 2)  
             return True
    return  **ThisClassName**.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

Comment: The `if not painter.isActive()` is useless, just create the painter with the target object as argument; also, a QBrush always has a SolidPattern as default, and within a paint event there's no need to end the painter, as it will be automatically closed on object destruction.

Comment: your comment is very great. Ok I will reedit.

Comment: Don't call `painter.begin(self.viewport())`, just create `painter = QPainter(self.viewport())`

Comment: Sorry, but that's not correct: if you create the painter with the target device as argument, you shall *not* call begin, as creating the instance like that automatically begins the painting operation.

Comment: If you are okay, pls rewrite my answer as you like. I ' m creddting you.

Comment: there's no need: just remove the `painter.begin()` :-)

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. I am sorry for the late answer. I tried to implement the code by myself. But i still make a mistake. I add the whole code to the answer.